# Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I was following a spring boot version 1.3.5 tutorial using other version (1.5.2.RELEASE) when I got these error messages:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

Here my classes:

```
package br.com.myspringproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

```
package br.com.myspringproject;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MySpringProjectApplication.class);
    }

}
```

---

```
package br.com.myspringproject.domain;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

---

```
package br.com.myspringproject.service;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import br.com.myspringproject.domain.Client;

@Service
public class ClientService {

    @Autowired
    ClientRepository clientRepository;

    public Client saveBLA(Client client){

        return clientRepository.save(client);       
    }

    public Collection<Client> findAllBLA(){
        return clientRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Client findOneBLA(Integer id){
        return clientRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public void deleteBLA(Client client){
        clientRepository.delete(client);
    }
}
```

---

```
package br.com.myspringproject.service;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.myspringproject.domain.Client;

@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client,Integer>{

}
```

---

```
package br.com.myspringproject.web;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.myspringproject.domain.Client;
import br.com.myspringproject.service.ClientService;


@RestController
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    ClientService clientService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/client", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Client> save(@RequestBody Client client){
        System.out.println("Call save ...");

        Client clientSaved = clientService.saveBLA(client);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(clientSaved,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/client", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Client>> findAll(){
        System.out.println("Call findAll ...");

        Collection<Client> clientList= clientService.findAllBLA();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(clientList, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/client/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Client> delete(@PathVariable Integer id){
        System.out.println("Call delete ...");

        Client clientFound = clientService.findOneBLA(id);

        if (clientFound == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        clientService.deleteBLA(clientFound);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/client", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Client> update(@RequestBody Client client){
        System.out.println("Call update ...");

        Client clientSaved = clientService.saveBLA(client);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(clientSaved,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

---

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/clientdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password:postgres
```

---

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.myspringproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySpringProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MySpringProject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

---

How you can see I didn't implement the @Configuration / @Bean  because I read in this documentation from Spring:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-a-datasource

"The spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is a special case in that it has different defaults depending on whether you are using an embedded database (create-drop) or not (none). The dialect to use is also automatically detected based on the current DataSource but you can set spring.jpa.database yourself if you want to be explicit and bypass that check on startup."

I really don't understand what is missing. Could someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: where is your `application.properties` in which directory... it must go in `src/main/resources` and not in `src/main/java`...

Comment: It is in src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

Following helped me to fix the issue

Change version `1.5.2.RELEASE` to `1.4.2.RELEASE` on POM file like shown below

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <!--  <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>--> 
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Good luck